# Github pages can't find svg files (Error 404)

Tags: reactjs, image, github, svg, github-actions

I develop React.js projects via Vite. I have  tags whose sources are SVG files. I address the tag below and it works on the local host:

```
<img src={`./static-job-listing/sass/${job.logo}`} alt="company logo"/>
```

I pushed the project on my GitHub repo and deployed it using GitHub actions. Everything is OK, but images will disappear. I get an error like this:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`
which I think, shows that the server can't find the specified address.
the repo: https://github.com/esNIMA/static-job-listing
the page: https://esnima.github.io/static-job-listing/

Comment: Did you commit the svg files to the repository? Only https://github.com/esNIMA/static-job-listing/tree/main/public works for me via https://esnima.github.io/static-job-listing/vite.svg .

Comment: Yes. All the files are there too.

Comment: Images loaded like that will work only if they are in the public folder. If you don't want to have them in the public folder you have to load them through the import https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-import-svgs-in-react-and-vite/. Also, you should try your code locally, it's not gh-pages fault, it won't work after build locally as well

Comment: Ok, for me https://github.com/esNIMA/static-job-listing/tree/main/public contains only vite.svg.

Comment: I put them in the public folder. it works locally, but when I open the gh-pages deploy, it has added another / to the address. local is: 'public/image/...' but on the pages is: 'public//image/...' I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Files in the public directory are served at the root path. So instead of:

```
<figure className="card--image">
          <img src={`public${job.logo}`} alt="company logo" />
</figure>
```

your code should be

```
<figure className="card--image">
          <img src={job.logo} alt="company logo" />
</figure>
```

Also make sure that you remove the leading "." in the image source. Example:

```json
{
    id: 2,
    company: "Manage",
    logo: "/images/manage.svg",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for a second and shows the logos. but they suddenly disappear again.  when I reload the page, logos will appear for a second but disappear again. what's the problem?

Comment: I checked the network tab. Firstly it loads the SVGs from "...../static-job-listing/images" and it's successful. but there is a second time that tries to load images from "...../images" and I'm not sure where this second loading comes from.

Comment: I worked finally! I put SVGs inside the public folder and used "./images/<logo name>.svg" as the address.